# Long converting to wrong time

Tags: java

I am trying to format a long until days, hours, minutes, seconds and found a method online.

```
public static String getTime(long time) {
    long enlapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(enlapsed);
    enlapsed -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(enlapsed);
    enlapsed -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(enlapsed);
    enlapsed -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(enlapsed);

    String result = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    return result.replace("0d ", "").replace("0h ", "").replace("0m ", "").replace("0s ", "");
}
```

and it was working but now suddenly inputting 4380 is giving 18151d 15h 33m 34s. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What did you expect the output to be for inputting 4380?

Comment: from milliseconds broken down to days hours minutes and seconds in the milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you found online calculates how much time has elapsed between now, and a given timestamp. You can test that this method works going to a site like [this](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), and multiplying the timestamp by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds, and passing that `long` to `getTime`.

The timestamp 4380 represents 4380ms after the Java Epoch, which is approximately 1 January 1970, which is about 18000 days ago.

If you want a more recent example, the timestamp `1568312340000` is just a few minutes before I started writing this, and doing `System.out.println(getTime(1568312340000L));` gives a smaller duration.

What you seem to want is not to calculate the elapsed time between now and a certain timestamp. You seem to just want to convert an amount of milliseconds to a duration expressed in days, hours, minutes and seconds.

The method works by first calculating the difference in milliseconds between now and the given timestamp, putting the difference into a variable called `enlapsed` (spelling mistake!) Then it calculates how many days, hours, minutes and seconds goes into `enlapsed` milliseconds. What you want is everything this method does except the first part where it calculates the difference, so you should delete this line:

```
long enlapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

and replace it with:

```
long enlapsed = time;
```

because you just want it to directly calculate what duration the `time` parameter represents.

Comment: I just discovered a new problem in my code sometimes the result is empty and says nothing at all

Comment: @Dan maybe because you input 0?

Comment: No, I input 803

Comment: @Dan 803ms is less than one second, so the method doesn't output anything. Do you want it to output `0s`?

Answer (score 0):

An input of 4380 to your method would return the time from the epoch minus about 4 seconds.  The epoch is 1970-01-01, so 18151 days/365.25 = 49.7 years - which in September of 2019 seems right to me.

Comment: My mistake was I was doing currentTime - enlapsed while It was already being done in the parameter while calling the method. But now I noticed sometimes the result is nothing just "" like I have 803 right now and I get "", whats causing this?

Comment: 803 millis is less than a second. your replace(...) calls eliminate it because everything is 0.

Comment: How could I get the remaining ms then?

Comment: Look at the code, follow the pattern.  Do you understand what your "enlapsed" variable is?  (You should fix that typo btw -  "elapsed")

Comment: I'd just need to add `enlapsed -= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds);` and the remaining elapsed amount is the ms, right?

Comment: That's right. Follow the pattern, at each step 'enlapsed' is the number of milliseconds you haven't yet accounted for with the larger time units.